# MapReduce, FileNotFoundException

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Hadoop 2.9.1, standalone installation.

The hdfs directory is organized by time (`yyyyMMdd/HH/mm`), like, `hdfs://server1:9000/foo/20190410/10/00`. And there're several files in each minute.

What I need to do is, process data for each hour, for example, process all data under `hdfs://server1:9000/foo/20190410/10`. So the mapreduce input setting is something like,

```
job.setInputFormatClass(org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileAsBinaryInputFormat.class);
    Path inputPath = new Path("hdfs://server1:9000/foo/20190410/10");
    org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileAsBinaryInputFormat.addInputPath(job, inputPath);
```

But I keep getting this,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://server01:9000/foo/20190410/10/00/data
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$29.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1533)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$29.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1526)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1526)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileInputFormat.listStatus(SequenceFileInputFormat.java:67)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:393)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:314)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:331)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:202)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1570)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1567)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1889)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1567)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1588)
        at com.misc.mr.TestJob.main(TestJob.java:54)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:239)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:153)
```

I have no idea why it try to access path `hdfs://server01:9000/foo/20190410/10/00/data`

If the input is a file instead of a folder (for example `hdfs://server1:9000/foo/20190410/10/00/part1`), it works fine.

Can anyone please help to give some explanation? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out.

Set `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive` to true.

Or

In code, call, `FileInputFormat.setInputDirRecursive(job, true)`